# Highlight parentesis in latex

Tags: latex, highlighting

[image]

the image is self explanatory, I recently switched to doom emacs and I'm still learning.

How can I fix this problem? I tried to switch off anything related to checkers in the init.el file but it doesn't help.

The problem is that rainbow-delimiters is recognizing (0,1] as a "not matching parenthesis" in latex environment, so it is highlighting everything from that point on. Now I really tried to disable the whole package in doom-emacs but I failed. It can easily toggled off with M-x rainbow-delimiters , but I want it disabled by default

Comment: You can try to see which modes are active with `describe-mode` and selectively disable them.
With non-evil keybindings you can use `M-x describe-mode` (possibly bound to `C-h m`, depending on your configuration)

Comment: What's the question? What is "this problem" that you want to fix? Are you asking how to _not_ highlight braces (they aren't parentheses, BTW)? So far, the question is unclear, so it risks being deleted. Please try to clarify the question. Thx.

Comment: If this happened when you switched to Doom Emacs, maybe you should ask this question to the maintainers of Doom Emacs?  Are you using a "default" Doom Emacs config, or is it a mix of Domm's and your own?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. As suggested by @einfeyn496 you can use `M-x describe-mode` to find the problematic mode. In this case the offending party is rainbow-delimiters-mode. Simply disable it with `M-x rainbow-delimiters-mode` and the highlighted brackets will no longer show.

Comment: Is there a way to keep `rainbow-delimiters` and still fix this highlighting issue?